# Creating Simultaneous Loops in Python

Tags: python, loops

I want to create a loop who has this sense:

```
for i in xrange(0,10):
for k in xrange(0,10):
     z=k+i
     print z

where the output should be

0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
```

Comment: Is that the real output you're looking for, or is this a simplified version of the problem?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip) to turn multiple lists (or iterables) into pairwise* tuples:

```
>>> for a,b in zip(xrange(10), xrange(10)):
...     print a+b
... 
0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18
```

But `zip` will not scale as well as `izip` (that sth mentioned) on larger sets.  `zip`'s advantage is that it is a built-in and you don't have to `import itertools` -- and whether *that* is actually an advantage is subjective.

*Not just pairwise, but *n*-wise.  The tuples' length will be the same as the number of iterables you pass in to `zip`.

Answer (score 11):

The [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module contains an [`izip`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) function that combines iterators in the desired way:

```
from itertools import izip

for (i, k) in izip(xrange(0,10), xrange(0,10)):
   print i+k
```

Comment: And of course `zip()` is a built-in function in Python.  And Python 3.x's `zip()` works exactly like `izip()` from Python 2.x

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in python - just have to make the tabs right and use the xrange argument for step.

`for i in xrange(0, 20, 2);
  print i`

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
i = range(0,10)
k = range(0,10)
for x in range(0,10):
     z=k[x]+i[x]
     print z
```

0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
16
18

Answer (score 0):

What you want is two arrays and one loop, iterate over each array once, adding the results.