# get values of true indixies from another array in python

Tags: python, arrays, boolean, series

I have one series of 8 TRUE and FALSE values:

```
boolean_massiv = pd.Series(np.concatenate([[False]*5,[True]*3]))
```

ALso I have another array of 8 different string values:

```
values_inside = pd.Series(['day', 'time', 'temperature', 'R.H.[%]', 'w.s.[m/s]', 'СС_down','СС_upper', 'precipitation'])
```

I want to get values with False indixies of First massiv:

```
'day', 'time', 'temperature', 'R.H.[%]', 'w.s.[m/s]'
```

How should I solve my problem?

Comment: If my answer is satisfying, please mark it as solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [simulanous loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452694/creating-simultaneous-loops-in-python).

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

boolean_massiv = pd.Series(np.concatenate([[False]*5,[True]*3]))

values_inside = pd.Series(['day', 'time', 'temperature', 'R.H.[%]', 'w.s.[m/s]', 'СС_down','СС_upper', 'precipitation'])

false_values = []

for i, j in zip(boolean_massiv, values_inside):
    if i == False:
        false_values.append(j)

false_Series = pd.Series(false_values)
```

This creates `false_Series` that contains the names from `values_inside` that correspond to value `False` in `boolean_massiv`.