# Python break one loop of two simultaneous loops while still continuing the 2nd loop

Tags: python

I created a simultaneous loop by referring to this [StackOverflow-page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452694/creating-simultaneous-loops-in-python),  like this:

```
s = '0123456789'         
index = 5
  
for i, j in zip(range(index-1,-1,-1), range(index+1,len(s))):
    print (s[i], s[j])
```

For the above code I get the following output:

```
4 6
3 7
2 8
1 9
```

But I need to break a loop if it's out of index and still continue the other loop, so for the above example I would like to get an output something like this:

```
4 6
3 7
2 8
1 9
0 None
```

And if I consider index as 3 I would like to get the output something like this:

```
2 4
1 5
0 6
None 7
None 8
None 9
```

Or if I consider index as 7 I would like to get the output something like this:

```
6 8
5 9
4 None
3 None
2 None
1 None
0 None
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [zip_longest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Could you please explain a bit more

Comment: Use `zip_longest` instead of `zip` and add a guard statement such as `s[i] if i is not None else None`.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko Thank You